# "filter" function in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, reinventing-the-wheel, scheme

I know this is a bit elementary, but I am highly uncomfortable writing Scheme code, and I want to make sure that what I'm doing is good practice.  I know mutation is frowned upon in Scheme.

I have no other source of review so I have come to you all.

```lisp
(define (filter-lst fn lst)
    (if (not (null? lst))
    (if (fn (car lst))
        (cons (car lst) (filter-lst fn (cdr lst)))
        (filter-lst fn (cdr lst))
        )
    '()
    )
)
```

Note: The function seems to be working according to a few test cases I ran.

As a follow-up PURELY STYLISTIC question, which of these is preferred?

#### #1

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
      (if (null? l1) l2
          (if (null? l2) l1
              (cons (car l1) (cons (car l2) (merge (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))))
```

#### #2

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
    (if (null? l1) l2
        (if (null? l2) l1
            (cons (car l1) (cons (car l2) (interleave (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))
        )
    )  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you catch yourself using nested `if`s, that's usually a sign you'd be better served by the cond form. (which is actually way more powerful than nested `if` due to a few quirks)

Here's how I'd clean that up

```
(define (filter-lst fn lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((fn (car lst)) 
         (cons (car lst)
               (filter-lst fn (cdr lst))))
        (else (filter-lst fn (cdr lst)))))
```

The above isn't entirely idiomatic (which would be to implement it as a one-liner fold with a lambda.) but does show off a few style notes. Of your choices I'd say #1 is closest to the preferred style.

First is where you may be tempted to tab, a double space will do as I do on the second line, its usually appropriate to distinct parts separate certain special forms particularly (define, let, cond). You really want to avoid creeping to the right any faster than necessarily.

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
  (if (null? l1) l2
      (if (null? l2) l1 (cons (car l1) (cons (car l2) (merge (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))))
```

Second is that if you split a function, there should be one argument per line, aligned to the start of the first argument

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
  (if (null? l1) 
      l2
      (if (null? l2) 
          l1 
          (cons (car l1) 
                (cons (car l2) 
                      (merge (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))))
```

And you see why cond is preffered again

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
  (cond ((null? l1) l2)
        ((null? l2) l1)
        (else (cons (car l1) 
                    (cons (car l2) 
                          (merge (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
```

And if a spot seems unwieldy there are often algorithmic simplifications that are worth considering

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
  (if (null? L1) 
      l2
      (cons (car l1)
            (merge l2 l1))))
```